# Is there a way to view list of TV shows downloaded to iPhone (iOS 6)?

Tags: ios, itunes

I have downloaded several TV shows that I purchased via AppleTV onto my iPhone (iOS 6).  However, I cannot find them on the phone using the iTunes app.  All I can get to via the "Purchased" button is the entire cloud of purchased shows. It is impossible to tell from this cloud list which shows are actually on my phone without clicking on each individual show.  I am going to be traveling without connectivity and just want to access the shows on my phone now.  I know the hack for accomplishing this with music / iTunes Match (going to Settings -> Music and switching off "See All Music").  Is there something similar I can do for TV shows - a way where I can simply view a list of what TV shows are currently on my phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way to see what is on the iPhone without seeing the items still in the cloud is to put the iPhone into Airline mode and then look at your TV shows.

As the phone cannot connect to iCloud it can only show what is actually available on the phone.